# How to set joined table result into Model Class

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-3, join

I have two tables like User and UserInfo

- UsersInfo
  UserId
  UserName
  Email
  Password
  LastLoginDate
- User
  UserId
  FirstName
  LastName
  PhoneNumber

**I would like to get data from database using join. i have written following query to get result from both above table**.

```
public ViewResult Index()
        {
            List<UserDetailModel> UsersCompleteDetails = (from u in db.Users
                                                          join l in db.UsersInfoes on u.UserId equals l.UserId
                                                          select new { u.UserId, u.UserName, u.Email, u.Password, u.LastLoginDate, l.FirstName, l.LastName, l.PhoneNumber }).ToList<UserDetailModel>;
            return View(UsersCompleteDetails);
        }
```

and following is the **Custom Class Model**

```
**public class UserDetailModel
{
    //Following details are comes from UsersInfo Table
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastLoginDate { get; set; }
    //Following details are comes from User Table
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
}**
```

but do not have any idea about how could i map the custom class with query result? right now it is giving me following **Error:**

Cannot convert method group 'ToList' to non-delegate type 'System.Collections.Generic.List'. Did you intend to invoke the method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specific error you are getting is because you don't have parenthesis after the call to `ToList` ie: `ToList<...>()`. However you have a larger issue in that you are trying to convert a list of an anonymous type to a typed list.

You could use a number of libraries out there to help you map your Entities to Model objects and vice versa like [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) but you could also just create conversion methods on the model and data objects themselves or use automatic property initialization which would be similar to your generation of the anonymous type.

The example below should work for your case, it isn't formatted pretty but should get the point across.

```
public ViewResult Index()
{
    List<UserDetailModel> UsersCompleteDetails = (from u in db.Users
                                                  join l in db.UsersInfoes on u.UserId equals l.UserId into userInfo
                                                  from info in userInfo.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                                  select new UserDetailModel() {  
        UserId = u.UserId, 
        UserName = u.UserName, 
        Email = u.Email, 
        Password = u.Password, 
        LastLoginDate = u.LastLoginDate, 
        FirstName = l.FirstName, 
        LastName = l.LastName, 
        PhoneNumber = l.PhoneNumber 
    }).ToList();

    return View(UsersCompleteDetails);
}
```

Comment: Quintin Robinson: this is accepted solution and i have resolved the issue with help of your solution. Thanks a lot for giving prompt solution. **I have one question how to modify join query if only Users table having records?**

Comment: @imdadhusen I have modified the example in my answer to illustrate a left join so you can get all `User` records regardless of them having a related `UserInfo` record.